# Proof of Continuity, but only in the unit circle minus a point

Tags: general-topology, inequality, continuity

I would like to prove the continuity the function
$$h(x,y)=x+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
For all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that 
$$0\lt\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1$$
using the $\delta$, $\epsilon$ definition of continuity.

I'm having a little bit of trouble choosing what $\delta$ should be. Can anybody give me a hint?

I think that the answer might use the fact that for $n\in \mathbb R$,
$$n-\frac{1}{4}\le n^2$$

**Please** do not write out a full answer - I just want a hint about how to choose $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Thanks!

Comment: For a starting point, you can neglect the $x+$ in the equation, since the sum of two continuous functions is continuous. For choosing $\delta$, a handy trick is that (if you know its derivative or gradient), $\delta = \epsilon * |\nabla h(x,y)|$ should always work. Although the algebra might not be ideal, necessarily, so you might want to take that derivative, and then taking something slightly smaller (but simpler to write out).

Comment: @AlexMeiburg Thanks for the hint! What is $\nabla$?

Comment: @Nilknarf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Definition

Comment: $\nabla$ is a notation for the gradient. That is, $|\nabla h| = \sqrt{(\partial h/\partial x)^2 + (\partial h/\partial y)^2}$.

Comment: Oh, okay, I will do some research on that. Thanks Alex and Simply!

Comment: @Nilknarf Wait, oops! I should have written $\delta = \epsilon / |\nabla h|$. I had it backwards. My bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex notes, we can neglect the $x+$ part of the function, and simply show that $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ is continuous (if you are uneasy about this, tell me and I'll say more).

I think the sensible thing to do here is interpret $g$ geometrically. Away from the origin (which is precisely the condition you insist on), $g(x,y)$ may be geometrically interpreted as $\cos \theta$, with $\theta$ the angle between $(x,y)$ and the $x$-axis.

Let $(u,v)$ be an arbitrary point with $0<\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}\le 1$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to find $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $(x,y)$ is inside the $\delta$-radius circle at $(u,v)$, the difference $|\cos \theta_{x}-\cos \theta_{u}|$ is less than $\varepsilon$. By continuity of $\cos$, this is the same as making $|\theta_{x}-\theta_{u}|$ appropriately small (I'm being intentionally vague as you only asked for a hint; I hope this doesn't make it more confusing).

That should be enough information to *draw a good picture*, and then try to spot the right $\delta$ based on that.

Comment: I should also note that I would, in general, have advised you to show that $h$ is a composition of continuous functions, rather than using the definition directly. But since you wanted to use the definition, here you are.

Comment: So you're saying I should show that
$$h(x,y)=\cos\arctan \frac{y}{x}$$
and then use the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: Not quite, as a composition I would say that $(x,y) \to x^2+y^2$, $x \to 1/x$ and so on are continuous. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Oh, and then use that the product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.